# Making a Template for a CPT created by a plugin

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, shortcode

Good day, I'm currently working with a new plugin which creates a custom post type for different rooms and I'm trying to create a custom template using Toolset, but other content is automatically prepended to my layouts on Toolset. I cannot see any extra code in toolset.

By default the plugin shows two pieces on the ROOM page. 1. Join button and 2. Recordings List

[Toolset Homepage](https://toolset.com/)

> single-bbb-room.php

even though creating a **single-bbb-room.php** works for removing the sidebar, author and comments, it seems the plugin is automatically adding shortcodes to the page contents. I cannot see how it would be doing that.

https://github.com/blindsidenetworks/wordpress-plugin_bigbluebutton

** ***ANY HELP WOULD BE GREATLY APPRECIATED.*** **

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is using a filter on the_content in line 300 of /includes/class-bigbluebutton.php

```
   // Display join room form.
            $this->loader->add_filter( 'the_content', $plugin_public, 'bbb_room_content' );
```

So you can probably add the following to your functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'bbb_room_content' );
```